# Google Analytics landing page (other)?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, landing-page

Most of my data about landing page says (other) and it seems like I really can't do anything with this data...

When I try to see the source or medium for example, it simply returns a blank line with everything at 0. Even when it's at (not set) I can usually get the medium or source... But for other, there seems to be simply nothing.

Anyone know what I can do to get this data? I am trying to get the information about where the users are landing mainly and how they get there...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your tracking code may be improperly implemented, or possibly that your site URL structure isn't friendly to Google Analytics. There is unfortunately no way to recover lost data, you can only fix the tracking and gather new, proper data.

How does your Page report look? Do you have a similar problem?

Does your URL structure use lots of query strings?

Another possibility is that this is false traffic: try adding Hostname as a second dimension. With almost no exceptions, hostnames other than the URL of your site are spam and should be ignored.